# How can I get the file names in directory with Chinese correctly in python?

Tags: python, r, unicode

How can I get the names list in the current working directory with **Chinese** appropriately in Python?

For example, in my demo folder, I have four files:  "folder_中文" "folder_a"    "folder_b"    "folder_c"

[image: screenshot]

in R I can use the following command to achieve this:

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "zh_cn.utf-8")
setwd("~/desktop/example")
filenames=list.files()
filenames
```

```
"folder_中文" "folder_a"    "folder_b"    "folder_c"
```

but I failed to achieve this in Python with Anaconda, although if I don't assign it to filenames, the output looks fine (see below); the Chinese is not correct in filenames.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
os.chdir('/Users/../Desktop/example')
! ls
filenames = ! ls
filenames
```

```
folder_a      folder_b      folder_c      folder_中文

['folder_a', 'folder_b', 'folder_c', 'folder_\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87']
```

but If I continue to type

```
print(filenames)
print(filenames[3])
```

The Chinese can be observed if I extract this specific element and print it directly.

```
['folder_a', 'folder_b', 'folder_c', 'folder_\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87']
folder_中文
```

The last thing I want to highlight is that, if I type Chinese directly, I can see Chinese correctly only if I use the *print* in a explicit manner. So with or without *print* makes a big difference on it.

```
print('中文')
'中文'
```

```
中文
Out[65]: '\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87'
```

My OS is Mac El Capitan (10.11.5) and the version of Anaconda is:

```
2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:05:08)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
```

Comment: When viewing a list or a string in a debugger or at the interactive prompt, Python displays the `repr()` of the string, which uses escape codes for non-ASCII.  `print` displays the `str()` of the string.  The content is the same, it's just the way it is displayed:  '中文' == '\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87'.  You have to print it to see it correctly.  Note that this is Python 2-specific.  Python 3 defaults to Unicode strings and will attempt to display them even in the `repr()` case.

Comment: I recommend you use built-in python functions for that, eg. `os.listdir()` will return the list of files in a directory.

Comment: Yes. `print str('中文')` returns the same thing as  `print '中文'`, but it's not the case if I only type `str('中文')`, so can I understand that there is no solution to answer the specific question that I raised as Python 2 is not compatible with Chinese to some extent?  I also notice that `os. listdir()` can't resolve the compatible issues as well.

Comment: Just tested in python 3, seems that it fits quite well with Chinese character.

Comment: It's not a problem with Chinese or `listdir`, you just need to understand the difference between the raw string `foo` and the string literal **repr**esentation of that string, `'foo'`, in which some characters may be expressed using escapes (`'foo' == 'f\x6Fo'`). Python 2 and 3 choose to escape different characters in their default string representations, but this doesn't make any material difference. Python 3 is still probably a better choice for you as it defaults to Unicode character strings instead of byte ones for filenames.

Comment: my question is how I can get the Chinese correctly in python 2? This is a common demand when I analyze the data.

Answer (score 0):

I recall an issue I helped with regarding Chinese characters for Python2. Python3 doesn't have the issue. I believe you need to add the following to your ~.bash_profile:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: is it equivalent to type `! export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` and `! export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in Jupyter ? I tried it  and also test the command with the option `zh_CN.UTF-8`. all don't work.